# Deserialize JSON to C# object to display nested array as string in grid

Tags: c#, arrays, json, winforms, datagridview

Everything run and Deserialize OK. Except the Roles is show up as System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

**Problem**

If I want to attach each field to a grid. Is there a way to show the collection as a string without looping through the Roles property?

JSON

```
[{
    "Name":"test",
    "Email": "test@test.com",
    "Roles": ["Admin","User","Guest"],
    "Age":"23"
},
{
  "Name":"test1",
  "Email": "test1@test.com",
  "Roles": ["Admin", "User" ,"Guest"],
  "Age":"33"
}]
```

Model

```
public class example
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialization

```
List<Exampe> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Exampe>>(bundle);
```

Comment: You need to clarify what the actual problem is because everything shown above should work as expected. Roles will be deserialized to a list of strings by default based on the type shown for the property.

Comment: What platform are you using? If Xaml use a value converter.

Comment: In future note that question like this appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Remember that providing a [mcve] should help clarify the actual problem most of the time.

Comment: I'm using Windows Form, DataGridView.  Thank you, Nkosi.  Next time, I will be more accurate with question and format.

Comment: Show how you assign the data to the data grid after deseiralization..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Nkosi mentioned, this is a XY problem. The problem is not deserialization, but rather how `DataGridView` handles a "complex" property type.

You can add a new property to display it:

- Either by directly modifying the class definition:

  ```
  public class Example
  {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string Email { get; set; }
      public string[] Roles { get; set; }
      public string Age { get; set; }

      public string RolesText => string.Join(", ", Roles ?? Array.Empty<string>());
  }
  ```
- Or by altering the `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`:

  ```
  dgv.DataSource = list.Select(x => new
  {
      x.Name, x.Email, x.Age,
      Roles = string.Join(", ", x.Roles ?? Array.Empty<string>()),
  }).ToList();
  ```

--

Bonus: Here is an generator for the 2nd approach:

```
string GenerateModelFormatter<T>()
{
    return new StringBuilder()
        .AppendLine("x => new")
        .AppendLine("{")
        .AppendLine(string.Join(",\n", typeof(T).GetProperties()
            .Select(x => x.PropertyType != typeof(string[])
                ? $"\t{x.Name} = x.{x.Name}"
                : $"\t{x.Name} = string.Join(\", \", x.{x.Name} ?? Array.Empty<string>())")))
        .AppendLine("}")
        .ToString();
}
```

Comment: I personally prefer the second option. clean and simple.

Comment: Thank you all for the help.  I was afraid of having to do something like this because I'm dealing with a class that has over 300+ properties and 50% of them will be an array of string[]. Big decision now..

Comment: You can use reflection or meta-programming to generate the lambda function:

Comment: That is a little bit out of my scope of knowledge but if you can point me in the right direction, i'm willing to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You have `Name` twice in your class - you probably want:

```
public class example
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you seem to want to get `string[]` instead of `List<string>`

`Roles` can be `string[]`

```
public class Example
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string[] Roles { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```