# Trying to fill a Datagridview in C# with values from a JSON but i only get 1 cell fill

Tags: c#, json, api, datagrid

I'm working on an API that sends me this JSON:

```
{
  "cuentas": [
    {
      "numero": "1234",
      "tipo": "inversion",
      "moneda": "peso",
      "disponible": 12345,
      "comprometido": 0.00,
      "saldo": 12345,
      "titulosValorizados": 12345,
      "total": 12345,
      "margenDescubierto": 12345,
      "saldos": [
        {
          "liquidacion": "inmediato",
          "saldo": 12345,
          "comprometido": 0.00,
          "disponible": 123,
          "disponibleOperar": 123
        },
        {
          "liquidacion": "hrs24",
          "saldo": 0.00,
          "comprometido": 0.00,
          "disponible": 0.00,
          "disponibleOperar": 123
        },
        {
          "liquidacion": "hrs48",
          "saldo": 0.00,
          "comprometido": 0.00,
          "disponible": 0.00,
          "disponibleOperar": 123
        },
        {
          "liquidacion": "hrs72",
          "saldo": 0.00,
          "comprometido": 0.00,
          "disponible": 0.00,
          "disponibleOperar": 123
        },
        {
          "liquidacion": "masHrs72",
          "saldo": 0.00,
          "comprometido": 0.00,
          "disponible": 0.00,
          "disponibleOperar": 0.0
        }
      ],
      "estado": "operable"
    },
    {
      "numero": "123",
      "tipo": "inversion",
      "moneda": "dolar",
      "disponible": 0.68,
      "comprometido": 0.00,
      "saldo": 0.68,
      "titulosValorizados": 123,
      "total": 123,
      "margenDescubierto": 0.0,
      "saldos": [
        {
          "liquidacion": "inmediato",
          "saldo": 0.68,
          "comprometido": 0.00,
          "disponible": 0.68,
          "disponibleOperar": 0.68
        },
        {
          "liquidacion": "hrs24",
          "saldo": 0.00,
          "comprometido": 0.00,
          "disponible": 0.00,
          "disponibleOperar": 0.68
        },
        {
          "liquidacion": "hrs48",
          "saldo": 0.00,
          "comprometido": 0.00,
          "disponible": 0.00,
          "disponibleOperar": 0.68
        },
        {
          "liquidacion": "hrs72",
          "saldo": 0.00,
          "comprometido": 0.00,
          "disponible": 0.00,
          "disponibleOperar": 0.68
        },
        {
          "liquidacion": "masHrs72",
          "saldo": 0.00,
          "comprometido": 0.00,
          "disponible": 0.00,
          "disponibleOperar": 0.0
        }
      ],
      "estado": "operable"
    }
  ],
  "estadisticas": [
    {
      "descripcion": "Anterior",
      "cantidad": 123,
      "volumen": 123
    },
    {
      "descripcion": "Actual",
      "cantidad": 6,
      "volumen": 123.80
    }
  ],
  "totalEnPesos": 123.123
}
```

then i have these classes to work with:

```
public partial class LecturaJson
        {
            public Cuenta[] Cuentas { get; set; }
            public Estadistica[] Estadisticas { get; set; }
            public double TotalEnPesos { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class Cuenta
        {
            public long Numero { get; set; }
            public string Tipo { get; set; }
            public string Moneda { get; set; }
            public double Disponible { get; set; }
            public long Comprometido { get; set; }
            public double Saldo { get; set; }
            public double TitulosValorizados { get; set; }
            public double Total { get; set; }
            public long MargenDescubierto { get; set; }
            public Saldo[] Saldos { get; set; }
            public string Estado { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class Saldo
        {
            public string Liquidacion { get; set; }
            public double SaldoSaldo { get; set; }
            public long Comprometido { get; set; }
            public double Disponible { get; set; }
            public double DisponibleOperar { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class Estadistica
        {
            public string Descripcion { get; set; }
            public long Cantidad { get; set; }
            public double Volumen { get; set; }
        }
```

then i use this code to get the JSON

```
var response =GetResponseGET(sURL + "/api/v2/estadocuenta", bearer);
```

then i add [] to make it deserizable

```
response = "[" +response+ "]";
```

then i deserialize:

```
var s = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LecturaJson>>(response);
```

then try tu fill a datagridview:

```
dtgvedc.DataSource = s;
```

the problem is that de DATAGRID dtgedc  (in the last code line) only gets 1 cell fullfiled... and nothing else...

Some of the values are new lists formed by new key-value groups

so its nos a plain dictionary.

Comment: I tested the code, there was no problem. The problem goes back to dtgvedc.DataSource. You cannot pass a list of lists to DataGrid. Modify dataGrid settings.

Comment: Thank you @meysamasadi . helped me alot!1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API result(LecturaJson) is the root class. The API result is not an array. The debugging helps to see what happens there. The array objects(Cuentas or Estadisticas ) can be set to the Datagridsources.

This code changes the response to an array.

`response = "[" +response+ "]";`

If you delete the previous code, you can change it without "List".

`var s = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LecturaJson>(response);`

```
dtgvedc.DataSource = s.Lectures;
dtgvedc2.DataSource = s.Cuentas;
```

dtgvedc2 must be a new datagridview.

Comment: Thank you Salih ... now its working, parcially... now i´m able to acces al the data but those inside class "Saldo[ ]" included inside "Cuenta [ ]" .

Comment: Binding nested gridview can be useful or extra property must be added to the Cuenta object with SaldosJson.
A [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51547311/deserialize-json-to-c-sharp-object-to-display-nested-array-as-string-in-grid#answer-51548119) for Adding extra property.
A [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63015161/binding-nested-gridview-with-datasource-datatable-in-c-sharp#answer-63029716) for Binding nested gridview(but this situation. Datasource is changing to the data table)